# Why is voltage in a coil multiplicative rather than additive?

Tags: electromagnetism

This may be a silly question - perhaps I just don't know how to ask it the right way. Regarding Faraday's Law, according to a second-semester physics student, the voltage around the perimeter of an open surface (or loop of wire) is

$$V_{loop} = -\frac{d\Phi_B}{dt}$$

Now, for every number of additional loops, $N$, the expression becomes

$$V_{coil} = -N\frac{d\Phi_B}{dt}$$

Why is this effect multiplicative rather than additive?

To clarify:

In my mind, additive to me means:

$$ V_{loop_1} + V_{loop_2} + \dots + V_{loop_n} $$

Where the expression for the voltage of the coil would be:

$$ V_{coil} = \sum_{n = 1}^{N} V_{loop_n} $$

EDIT:

I'm an idiot and I've just asked what multiplication was, sorry. I realize that I had to assume each loop was identical to get the second equation. Does this work for loops that aren't identical as well?

Comment: Since you're calling this multiplicative, could you also write out what the expression would look like if it was additive? (To me, $Nz$, is $z+z+...+z$, with $N$ $z$'s being *added* together.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you were expecting instead — I can think of a few different things. Could you [edit] your question to describe the kind of "additive" behavior you would have expected?

Comment: @Yejus yes, that's my bad

Answer (score 1):

$V_{\mathrm{loop}} + V_{\mathrm{loop}} + \cdots + V_{\mathrm{loop}}= NV_{\mathrm{loop}} = V_{\mathrm{coil}}$.

Comment: Would you not be able to generalize this if each loop were not identical?